Gronwall-type Inequality for Measurable Sets
Let $f$ be a function defined on $[0,1]$, and let $A_\epsilon \subset [0,1]$ be a measurable subset. I'm interested in whether there is a Gronwall-type inequality for measurable sets of the following form:
$$
\left| \int_{A_\epsilon} \dot{f}(t) \, dt \right| \leq C \int_{A_\epsilon} |f(t)| \, dt + C_\epsilon
$$
where:

$\dot{f}(t)$ denotes the derivative of $f(t)$,
$C$ is a constant,
$C_\epsilon$ is a small constant dependent on $\epsilon$,
and $A_\epsilon$ is a measurable subset of $[0,1]$.

Is such an inequality valid for measurable subsets, and under what conditions on $f$ (e.g., regularity or growth conditions) would it hold?
Any insights or references to similar results would be appreciated!
